# Strange removal of a decent answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

The only answer provided to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15880/gun-violence-in-chicago) (also automatically removed, so now it is accessible to 2K users only) was "hammered" by a moderator.

However, the question had and has a good score and there are no comments to justify its tragic end. Its edit history indicates complete removal and then a restore.

It is true that the question is rather poor, but the answer looked fine. Removal of the answer most probably led to automatic removal of the question ("dead" - low score, old and no answers).

Note: I am not sure if it matters, but both users (question author and answer author) are currently suspended.

**Question: Why was the answer removed?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a co-incidence of several events in a row:

1. There was a content dispute about one of the user's answers (see [this Meta post](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2992/))
2. Instead of editing their answers, as the community suggested, the user got furious and started vandalizing their own posts across the site — see [1](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/15935/revisions), [2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/16550/revisions), [3](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/15915/revisions), [4](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/15974/revisions), [5](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/16496/revisions)
3. For some posts, other users rolled back the recent edits
4. For other posts, other users decided to remove the vandalized posts altogether (which, I admit, might be a better choice than the rollback)
5. After deletion of its single answer, the question "Gun violence" became orphan (negative score, no answers) and subsequently deleted by the SE maintenance script
6. Note: the answer has rollback edit *after* it has been deleted, so this couldn't prevent the maintenance script to delete it.

Comment: So, if I got it right, the answer removal by the moderator was done due to author's intention to do so (although the author used an unusual way of expressing it).

Comment: @Alexei, Well, if the author were silently deleted their posts, it might get unnoticed. But vandalized answers sooner or later attract someone else's attention…

Comment: Vandalized.  Interesting choice of words when Mods are deleting the posts for me :-D

Comment: @Venture2099, your answers are really good. Vandalizing them — even if you have a content dispute over another post(s) — is certainly not an option. Can't speak for everyone, but I appreciate your posts and I've learned a lot from many of them. So I sincerely hope you will be able to settle this problem in a peaceful manner. Seriously. And welcome back!